# How ELF file is laid out in memory

Tags: elf

When an ELF file is run and its various segments are loaded into memory, is there a way to know in advance how the segments will be arranged in relation to each other?  That is, could I know, for example, that the rodata segment comes after the bss segment?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> is there a way to know in advance how the segments will be arranged in relation to each other?

Yes. There are two types of ELF files: `ET_EXEC` and `ER_DYN`. The former is for executables, the latter for PIE executables and shared libraries.

An `ET_EXEC` segments will be in memory in *exactly* the location they were linked at. The executable will not work if its segments are loaded anywhere else.

You can examine the linked-at addresses with `readelf -Wl a.out`.

For `ET_DYN`, the segments will be loaded at a *single fixed* offset of where they were linked. That is, if the first `PT_LOAD` segment is linked at address `0x0`, and loaded at address `0x1234000`, then you can add `0x1234000` to the `p_vaddr` of every subsequent segment to determine where it is loaded in memory.

> could I know, for example, that the rodata segment comes after the bss segment?

There is no such thing as `rodata` and `bss` segment -- they are *sections*. To see which segment these sections are assigned to, use `readelf -Wl`.

Comment: Thanks.  I seem to have trouble remembering the difference between sections and segments.

Comment: Please allow a follow-up question.  Do the program headers correspond to the segments?  I notice that the output of `readelf -Wl` for my sample ELF contains nine of each.

Comment: @DanielWalker Yes: program headers describe ELF segments, and there is 1:1 relationship. Note: not all segments are loadable, only the ones with `.p_type == PT_LOAD`. Note: non-loadable segments may overlap and be included as part of some loadable ones.

Comment: Perfect!  That's just what I needed to know.  Thank you!